# Getting checkbox value from <span> with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/bootstrap.html

Im using the above css files and code to make a toggle switch. I want to check which result is checked but I have never worked with something that uses the `<span></span>` tags.

I have tried searching to find the answer to my question but I just have no luck searching the right thing so I decided to ask.

my code:

```
<label class="checkbox toggle well" onclick="">
            <input id="view" type="checkbox" checked />
            <span>
            Spotlight
            <span>Off</span>
            <span>On</span>
            </span>
            <a class="btn btn-primary slide-button"></a>
            </label>
```

How do i get a value which corresponds with which ones selected?

If you can redirect me to a post with the answer or answer my question I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: off value should correspond to checkbox being unchecked and vice a versa

Comment: there are many solutions including testing the text inside the span, but I prefer to add an data-* attribute to the span and then use it like `<span data-state="off">Off</span>` and `<span data-state="on">On</span>`, then access it using `$(spanelement).data('state')`

Comment: I removed my answer as I missread the question. sry.

Comment: Should I give the span elements unique ids, in order to use with your jquery?

Comment: Thank you for trying Sebastian ahha didn't even get a chance to see your answer!

Comment: No problem, my duty was to delete and to inform that I made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('#view:checked') ? "it's on" : "it's off";
```

You don't have to touch those spans in order to get the checked value.

Comment: Or user $('#view').checked to get a true or false answer directly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
if($('#view').is(':checked')) {
 alert('on');
}
else {
 alert('off');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear response! I would set yours as the correct answer but Shomz answered first and its only fair!

Comment: Ok. No problem. But both are different techniques. That's all