# Return the rows in a JQuery datatable when specific "Bootstrap" checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

**1. Why my code doesn't work with *Bootstrap checkboxes*:**

The javascript below would work perfectly if (bootstraps checkboxes) had the property "checked" in the inputs, but it is setting the class="checked" in the parent span. As below:

```
<span class="checked">
   <input type="checkbox" value="9577" class="overtimeapproval">
</span>
```

This javascript returns an array with all the rows that I need:

```
$("#mytable:has(.overtimeapproval:checked)").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
```

**2. What I suppose I have to do for Bootstrap checkboxes**

To make the same javascript working with bootstrap checkboxes I need something like:

**todo:**    `$("#mytable:has(.overtimeapproval:parent:span:checked)").dataTable().fnGetNodes();`

**How can I do the jquery selector above?**

Comment: you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501802/getting-checkbox-value-from-span-with-jquery

Comment: This doesn't really help much, I need a selector to filter when the parent span has the class ".checked" @VimalanJayaGanesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#mytable:has(.overtimeapproval:parent.checked)").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
```

I think this can help you.

Comment: No, it is not working, "checked" is a class of the span object, how can I select when there is a ".checked" class? @lightbringer

Comment: doesn't has() function do that? otherwise you can go from top to bottom instead of going backward, something like `#mytable:has(span.checked input.overtimeapproval)`

Comment: This javacript worked perfectly! Even being a "Bootstrap checkbox": $($("#mytable").dataTable().fnGetNodes()).has('.overtimeapproval:checked')

Answer (score 0):

I could do exactly what I needed with the javascript below:

```
$($("#mytable").dataTable().fnGetNodes()).has('.overtimeapproval:checked')
```

> It seems that Bootstrap checkboxes work properly with the :checked
>   selector.